# Stack in Portainer is limited, although it is created with the Portainer API

Tags: api, portainer

I am trying to deploy a stack via Portainer API. This is working. But the Portainer UI tells me, that the access to this stack limited, although I have created it with Portainer.

[image: Stack list on Portainer UI]

If I look at the response after deploying the stack via API, I see that there is a part called "Resource Control".

```
{
"Id": 12,
"Name": "test",
"Type": 1,
"EndpointId": 2,
"SwarmId": "MySwarm",
"EntryPoint": "docker-compose.yml",
"Env": null,
"ResourceControl": {
    "Id": 11,
    "ResourceId": "2_test",
    "SubResourceIds": [],
    "Type": 6,
    "UserAccesses": [],
    "TeamAccesses": [],
    "Public": false,
    "AdministratorsOnly": true,
    "System": false
},
"Status": 1,
"ProjectPath": "/data/compose/12",
"CreationDate": 1674110389,
"CreatedBy": "admin",
"UpdateDate": 0,
"UpdatedBy": "",
"AdditionalFiles": null,
"AutoUpdate": null,
"GitConfig": null,
"FromAppTemplate": false,
"Namespace": "",
"IsComposeFormat": false}
```

Is this the reason for the limited access on the UI? And is there any way to deploy a stack via API and have full access?